# TV series on human evolution where some people have some difference in their makeup making them not Homo sapiens

Tags: story-identification, tv

Being a bit vague here it was a series I saw in the 1990-2005 on the sci-fi channel in Europe. The main plot is that there a two geneticists and they find some people have x% difference in their makeup making them not *Homo sapiens*.

I have some thoughts that it was called *47%* or similar but cannot find it.
I remember there was a young woman with red hair and a guy they were working for a lab but when they found this difference they ended up working on it "off the books" while the "evolved humans" were trying to find them.

It was shown on TV in Sweden about the same time as the *First Wave* series.
It was a North American series (I would be inclined to think from Canada)
Sorry though that's about all the things I can remember which is why it's so hard to find. Even tried looking at the lists of series from the Sci-Fi channel.

Comment: Was there anything else you remember about this that you can [edit] in? Even if you're not 100% sure on it ever little thing can help us identify this for you.

Comment: Didn't you mean [_First Wave_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0160277/) instead of _5th Wave_? The former is a 2000s TV show, and the latter (as far as I know) is a 2010s book series that got a movie 2-3 years ago.

Comment: oops correct first wave...just goes to show we men cannot do two things at once :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it doesn't match the proposed series title, could it be *[Prey](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Prey)* (warning, TVTropes page)?

> A short-lived science-fiction TV series that premiered on ABC in 1998. The show lasted only for a single season (13 episodes).
>
> Dr. Sloan Parker (Debra Messing) is an anthropologist studying genetic variation in humans. After her mentor is killed by the serial killer she was studying, Sloan discovers that the killer's DNA is substantially different (1.6%) from human to be considered a new Human Subspecies. In fact, after analyzing several cases involving serial killers, she determines that many of the killers have the same genetic markers. This new species is characterized by high intelligence, sociopathic attitude towards normal humans, and extreme aggression. Several people are made aware of this, and Sloan even theorizes that this new evolutionary development may be due to Global Warming.

Dr. Parker's hair is more red highlights than red, but she does work for a lab, and works with Tom Daniels, a federal agent, to track down the new human species.

[image: Dr. Sloan Parker]

Comment: thanks that Prey was it....great work :)

Comment: @NormSmith: Congrats! Sorry that there's only a single season for you to track down, but at least some of the episodes are on YouTube, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6j6QsK2c2EE

Comment: "Sloan even theorizes that this new evolutionary development may be due to Global Warming." Well...at least the writers know that global warming is real?